# Azure DataSync failed due to Bulk Insert command

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-sync

Data Sync is failed  due to below.I'm trying to add newly created table to the sync group.That table is having 4 records only.I tried deleting the sync group and recreating the sync group again.Please check the inner Exception.My databases Hub and Destination are both Azure SQL database only.

Sync failed with the exception "An unexpected error occurred when applying batch file sync_0aa1a62ac6c5423e82b16d2f148874be5d4e46c336ce42609ae07e193b81f169\f7a1b4f6-56c1-4ac2-ad65-6b15369c9e9a.batch. See the inner exception for more details. Inner exception: Failed to execute the command 'BulkInsertCommand' for table 'dbo.CoachingTaskCategories'; the transaction was rolled back. Ensure that the command syntax is correct. Inner exception: SqlException ID: 8e69fdc4-0a3c-47c1-9ba5-7cc212a94b91, Error Code: -2146232060 - SqlError Number:8106, Message: SQL error with code 8106 For more information, provide tracing ID ‘262c340b-7c5c-4771-8319-1a08773584b5’ to customer support."

Comment: Please show the full 'BulkInsertCommand' .

Comment: when we create data sync setup some procedures and triggers will be automatically created.

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Comment: In my case, I missed  adding Identity property.

Comment: Did you mean that the tables in Member database also should have identity properly if source tables in Hub database have?

Comment: Yes, Target table should also have identity property ..if source table have